How to inject a ViewModel object in composable functions?
I have an app where I inject a ViewModel object directly in the MainScreen:
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: ItemsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopBar(
                onClick = {
                    viewModel.signOut()
                }
            )
        },
        content = {
            ItemsContent(
                items = viewModel.getItems()
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FAB(
                onClick = {
                    viewModel.addItem("ABC")
                }
            )
        }
    )
}

Is it recommended to inject the ViewModel object only once in the MainScreen screen or is it ok if I inject the same ViewModel object inside each composable function, TopBar, ItemsContent and FAB?

You should keep your composables as independent as possible from view models. That means that you usually only want your top-most composables (your Screens) to hold an instance of the view model. Everything below that only receives the states and callbacks of the view model that it actually needs, passed as parameters.
The way you did it in your question looks good. This way the other composables have simple parameters and can be more easily tested and reused.

This is correct.
You shouldn't pass ViewModel instances down to other composables.
Composables consume the screen UI state hoisted in the ViewModel. You should inject the ViewModel instance in your screen-level composables to provide access to business logic.
For more details Refer ViewModel and State holders and UI State

Your way is correct, keep composable functions independent from viewmodel
